# PDO keeps throwing error on email check?

Tags: php, sql

```
if(!empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $params = array( ':email' => $email );
    $sql = "SELECT `email` FROM `tablename` WHERE email = :email";
}

else return false;

$stmt = $user->query($sql, $params);
echo ( $stmt->rowCount() > 0 ) ? $exists = false : $exists = true;
if($exists) { header("Location:theurlifemailalreadyexists");  };
```

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]:
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com' at
>   line 1 in **** on line 87

How can I get it to stop throwing that thing?  It's throwing it at the email address EVERY TIME.

Comment: For simplicity, I'm not showing my sanizing of the email, but it DOES get sanitized.

Comment: If you use PDO, use parameter binding. I suppose $user is not PDO connection object, thus your code doesn't show how your code "gets" sanitized (no, it doesn't).

Answer (score 3):

What's this?

```
 SELECT `email` FROM `tablename` WHERE email = {$user->secure($_POST['email'])}
                                               ^
```

This should be

```
SELECT `email` FROM `tablename` WHERE email = :email
```

Since the parameter you are replacing is  `:email`

```
$params = array( ':email' => $email );
```

Comment: Looks as though I tried a few things with a cached page.  And now it works fine.  Thanks.